# Is travelling to persue a career haram for a female Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, women, travelling, mahram

I am a Muslim female and I live my life (well, I try to) according to the Quran and sunnah of the prophet (may pbuh).  I want to teach abroad in other countries as my career. Is this haraam?

I know we're not allowed to travel without a mahram, etc., and it's easy for someone to just say "well, teach where you live, it's the same thing". But it isn't - I want to travel.

Is this a selfish thing to say? because I feel greedy for saying it.

I know my parents would be against it and I feel absolutely terrible for making them sad by arguing my point. My parents are ill so I don't want to make them sad at all. But I feel sad too because I can't pursue my passion.

Someone could say: get married then travel with your husband so you have a mahram.  So would I just advertise this as "who wants to marry me so I can take you with me to pursue my career" - that's a bit mean if I just got married so I can have a mahram. In all honesty, I don't really want to get married any time soon.

I could just forget about this career and do something else but that isn't me being authentic to myself.

Comment: You seem to understand that it's haram to travel without mahram; it sounds more like a conflict between your wish to follow religious precepts and a wish for a career that involves haram. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Growing up I have seen unmarried Muslim women traveling for work. The work isn't haraam. The travel part, I don't think is haraam, but I'm not sure. Most of the time, these women travel together.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones and has your travel plans had to change after becoming a Muslim?

Comment: I haven't avoided travelling, and I'm still making plans to travel.  I partly need to go for conferences for work, and I'm also the adventurous type.  (I'm not sure how great this all is Islamically.  However, travelling to Muslim countries certainly played a role in why I'm a Muslim now.)

Comment: This question would need some kind ijtihad if you'd like to have an answer for your case. Basically a women isn't allowed to travel without a mahram, or a safe group or at least the permission of her guardian or spouse. I guess classical scholars would reject the idea of a woman trying to follow a career, and they would even have more objection if it is a travelling career.

Comment: @Medi1Saif why ijtihad? Its just clear that its not allowed for women to travel without mahram. Islam is what it is, its ules cannot be changed over time, you know it very well. Yes, i agree there are exceptions(few) but this case is no exception, Its just a willingness of a person.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal Maybe relevant: http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=3019&text=travel

Comment: @G.Bach Has a point. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not an Muslim peer support group. If she already follow the opinion that it is not allowed, then it becomes a support or advice question. Maybe the question could be asked in another way, but as it is now, it is either too broad, unclear what she really is asking, off topic or primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to provide a view of the other point of view.

In the answer to the question: "[Can a woman travel alone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39711/15201)" it is concluded that:

> **a woman is free to travel alone as she is safe and no harm is expected.**

*Your question is based on the "allowance of a woman to travel alone", when  this variable changes, it's very likely that your question does too. Truly without this factor, it is hard to come to the conclusion and say it is haram. Following the opionion mentioned above that it isn't forbidden to travel alone, **the answer to your question is more likely to be: "no it's not a haram".***

Answer (score -1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

Sister, it's actually excellent that you are concerned about this issue and seeking solution in light of shariah.

Coming to the question, **it seems you already know and it does not need any more clarification that traveling without a mahram is not allowed for women**, even they cannot go to hajj without a mahram, if mahram is not available for a woman and she has all the resources and will to do hajj, she still cannot perform hajj without mahram *(some fuqaha make exception specially for the hajj traveling with some trusty people with consent of mahram though this exception is not said to be for any other kind of traveling until or unless necessary enough to make an exception).*

So, its like you want to follow shariah, but you are not liking some of its rule, this is where the real test is. Keeping aside the argument of teach where you live etc, still! **we have to follow shariah in all aspects of our lives.** Something which you know shariah is clear about, and you don't like it, this is no excuse or exception for that law of shariah.

***If you leave something you like for the will of Allah, he will surely give you something better, in this world and in hereafter.***

### Let's have some quotes :) :

Allah says in Quran:

> **Indeed, Allah has *purchased* from the believers *their lives* and their
>   properties [in exchange] for that they will have Paradise**. They fight
>   in the cause of Allah , so they kill and are killed. [It is] a true
>   promise [binding] upon Him in the Torah and the Gospel and the Qur'an.
>   And who is truer to his covenant than Allah ? So rejoice in your
>   transaction which you have contracted. And it is that which is the
>   great attainment. **Quran 9/111**

And in a hadeees it says:

> Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be
>   upon him, said, **“The world is a prison for the believer and a paradise
>   for the unbeliever.”**
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2956

([Explanation here](http://dailyhadith.adaptivesolutionsinc.com/hadith/A-Muslim%E2%80%99s-Prison.htm))

These quotes are clear that **a believer is not supposed to follow his own wills in this world**, if he want to succeed in hereafter. It's a trade, a very profitable trade. Giving up something in this temporary world for hereafter which is never ending life, and where you can do whatever you want!

> **And whosoever puts his trust in Allâh, then He will suffice him**. Surat
>   At-Talâq: 3

And in hadees quoted in musnad imam ahmed bin humbal

> The messenger of Allah صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم said **“You will never leave
>   something for the sake of Allah, but Allah will give you something
>   better in return.**”

Another ayah, Allah describes reward for the people who believe and follow his commandments.

> He prepared for you in which there is that which no eye has seen no
>   ear has heard and it has never crossed the mind of man. [bukhari] **you
>   will have there whatever your heart desire**. Surah al-Nahl 16:31

By these, i want you to put your trust in Allah, that if you leave something for the sake of Allah, he will surely replace that with something better.

**As conclusion**, there is no exceptional case for which the law of shariah can be avoided. So, you HAVE to follow shariah and either not travel(and live there) without a mahram, or look up for a mahram who has matching passion or lives there or anything.

**May Allah give you best reward for your efforts.**

### Allah knows best

Answer (score -2):

Why would it be haram? As long as you aren't doing anything wrong, there shouldn't be a problem, there isn't any ruling in Islam on women working.

Comment: Question is clear that she already know it is not permissible for women to travel without mahrams. ANd she is trying to look for a way around. How come you are declaring it non-haram? And would you mind defining your definition of WRONG?